# Firebase/Angularfire: accessing static values of observables

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Assume I have a Firebase object with names for some IDs:

```
people: {
  key1: {name: "Bob"},
  key2: {name: "Sally"},
  ...
}
```

I create an `AngularListObservable`:

```
this.people$ = this.angularFireDatabase.list('people');
```

and feed this into the template as

```
<span *ngFor="let person of people$ | async">Hello {{person.key}}</span>
```

Now assume I want to create a new element in `people`, but base its name on the current number of keys. This requires me to somehow access a static version of `people` to count its elements. I have found the following three approaches:

**One**: maintain a current static value via a subscription in `ngOnInit`:

```
private currentPeople;

ngOnInit() {
  this.people$.subscribe(people => this.currentPeople = people);
}
```

Then

```
public create() {
  this.people.push({name: "person " + (this.currentPeople.length + 1)});
}
```

However, this requires me to keep track of the subscription and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`.

**Two**: use `take` on the observable:

```
public create() {
  this.people$.take(1).subscribe(people =>
    this.people.push({name: "person " + (people.length + 1)});
  );
}
```

But will this work reliably in getting the *current* value of the observable?

**Three**: back off into Angular database itself, entering the world of References and Snapshots, and do

```
public create() {
  this.people$.$ref.once("value").then(peopleSnapshot =>
    this.people.push({name: "person " + (peopleSnapshot.numChildren() + 1)});
}
```

Are any of three approaches considered best practices, or what other pluses and minuses do they have?

Answer (score 0):

For static vars you can use an src/environments/environment.ts folder to hold static information in json format and access them using `environment.myvar`

In your app.modules.ts you would put

```
imports: [ AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```